# Trouble with understanding how to do authentication from node and angular

Tags: node.js, angular

So I'm currently building a really small app to prove a concept using Node, passport, and angular.

I'm having trouble trying to get the users information from the server to my front end because of the way that twitter authentication works. And I thought I'd reach out to see if any of you can help me understand.

Basically my problem is that I call my backend localhost:8000/auth/twitter and that redirects to the twitter auth page, and then calls a callback which is in my backend. At that point I have user data, and all is good. However I can't just send that to my frond end as I have to do a redirect.

If I redirect to my front end: localhost:4200/ I no longer have the session data that is included on the request from the backend. So I can't redirect to the front end.

I can redirect to a page in the backend, and I have all the data available to be, but that doesn't really help me as I need to send it down to my angular app.

What would be a good way of doing this?

Is it possible?

How can I make sure that the user that is using my site is authenticated when calling backend routes to do things?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you'd like to see my code, I can show it but I'm not sure if it would help, as I'm just trying to understand a concept.

Comment: Not angular, but would this help? https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/oauth-nodejs-javascript/

Comment: In production, is your node application going to serve the angular assets? Also when you say "cant send data to angular", have you considered exposing endpoints that are protected via passport or similar that expose the data you need to the angular application? As in oauth flow, redirect to node, redirect to angular, send http requests with credentials to protected node endpoints.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky so I'm thinking of sending the auth code attached to my url to angular then I will save that in a cookie, and use that cookie auth code to make requests to my backend endpoints.

Comment: @uster1 At least start with, get all that set up, then if you have issues, update your question with relevant code.